# Получение списка значения по ключу из вложенного массива JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, словари

*Возможно вопрос покажется слишком легким, но он меня завел в ступор...*

Как мне получить список значений, которые находятся по ключу **PHONE** - **VALUE**?

```
0:
ID: "40"
PHONE: Array(2)
    0: {ID: "186317", VALUE_TYPE: "MOBILE", VALUE: "+3333333333", TYPE_ID: "PHONE"}
    1: {ID: "190893", VALUE_TYPE: "WORK", VALUE: "+22222222222", TYPE_ID: "PHONE"}
TITLE: "Title 1"

1:
ID: "47"
PHONE: Array(3)
    0: {ID: "310047", VALUE_TYPE: "MOBILE", VALUE: "+777777777", TYPE_ID: "PHONE"}
    1: {ID: "310048", VALUE_TYPE: "HOME", VALUE: "+6666666666", TYPE_ID: "PHONE"}
    2: {ID: "310049", VALUE_TYPE: "OTHER", VALUE: "+1111111111", TYPE_ID: "PHONE"}
TITLE: "Title 2"
.....
```

Я пытаюсь сделать это через цикл:

```
var numberList = [];

for (data in resultData){
        numberList.push(resultData[data].PHONE);
}
```

И при выводе через `numberList.VALUE` получаю *undefined*

Comment: `resultData[0].PHONE[0].VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

```
const numberList = resultData.map(itm => itm.PHONE.map(ph => ph.VALUE));
```

В результате, массив `numberList` должен содержать подмассивы с номерами, т.е. например

```
[
  ["+3333333333", "+22222222222"],
  ["+777777777", "+6666666666", "+1111111111"]
]
```

Если же хочется получить одномерный массив (потеряв связанность с `resultData` по индексу), то такой массив можно получить выражением `numberList.flat(1)`.

Comment: если же в некоторых значениях отсутствуют массивы с  **PHONE**, как избежать возникновения ошибки?

Comment: @Fox, использовать либо операторы `?.` и `??`, либо условные (проверяя тип значения) - по конкретной ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = { 
  0: {
    ID: "40",
    PHONE: [
            {ID: "186317", VALUE_TYPE: "MOBILE", VALUE: "+3333333333", TYPE_ID: "PHONE"},
            {ID: "190893", VALUE_TYPE: "WORK", VALUE: "+22222222222", TYPE_ID: "PHONE"}
           ],
    TITLE: "Title 1"},

  1: {
    ID: "47",
    PHONE: [
            {ID: "310047", VALUE_TYPE: "MOBILE", VALUE: "+777777777", TYPE_ID: "PHONE"},
            {ID: "310048", VALUE_TYPE: "HOME", VALUE: "+6666666666", TYPE_ID: "PHONE"},
            {ID: "310049", VALUE_TYPE: "OTHER", VALUE: "+1111111111", TYPE_ID: "PHONE"}
           ],
    TITLE: "Title 2"}
}

let arr = []
Object.values(obj).forEach(el1 => el1.PHONE.forEach(el2 => arr.push(el2.VALUE)))
console.log(arr)
```